# URL format for Google News RSS feed

Tags: rss, google-news

Google deprecated the old RSS feed URL format December 1st 2017 ([deprecation notice](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/news/Sx5lr6wuL_Q)), in addition to that they dropped the button in the Google News interface to generate a RSS URL ([news mentioning this change](https://www.seroundtable.com/google-news-rss-feed-gone-25795.html)).

This means that there is no public or documented method of generating a new RSS link. The only [documentation](https://support.google.com/news/publisher-center/answer/4203?hl=en) they have is out of date since they changed the interface.

What is the new format for generating a RSS feed for a Google News topic?

Comment: Well it seems today they completely broke the old feeds. Now they are all giving files that have the `<generator>NFE/5.0</generator>` opposed to the `<generator>NFE/1.0</generator>` tag.  Super annoying since these come in a different format.

Comment: The links google provides in it's rss news feed is now censored.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Found an up-to-date library ([1](https://github.com/NichtJens/GoogleNewsRSS2OPML)) that uses Google News RSS.

The URL new format seems to be:

**Top news:**

```
https://news.google.com/news/rss
```

**By major topic:**

```
https://news.google.com/news/rss/headlines/section/topic/{topic}
```

Where {topic} is one of the following values: `WORLD NATION BUSINESS TECHNOLOGY ENTERTAINMENT SPORTS SCIENCE HEALTH`

**By any/custom topic:**

Once at https://news.google.com, browse to the desired topic, for example [this](https://news.google.com/topics/CAAqIQgKIhtDQkFTRGdvSUwyMHZNR056T1hFU0FtVnVLQUFQAQ?hl=en). Identify the topic ID in its URL, e.g. <sub>CAAqIQgKIhtDQkFTRGdvSUwyMHZNR056T1hFU0FtVnVLQUFQAQ</sub>, and use the format:

```
https://news.google.com/rss/topics/{id}?hl={lang}
```

In the format above, essentially `rss/` is added after `https://news.google.com/`.

**By geolocation:**

```
https://news.google.com/news/rss/headlines/section/geo/{location}
```

Not sure about the formatting for the {location} parameter

**By search query:**

```
New link: https://news.google.com/rss/search?q={query}
Old link: https://news.google.com/news/rss/search/section/q/{query}
```

Where the {query} parameter is a free text search

**Specifying country and language:**

For example if you wish to have news in Swedish and located from Swedish sources, add the following query string to the URL to change country and language to sv-SE: 
`?hl=sv&gl=SE&ceid=SE%3Asv`

Comment: any REST API if you know any?

Comment: @NeelamPursnani I don't know of any REST-API I'm afraid. Only found this by digging around in someone elses source code.

Comment: That's awesome, now I can read google news without ads! For Hebrew I use:  https://news.google.com/news/rss/?hl=he&gl=IL&ceid=IL%3Ahe

Comment: The geolocation seems to support some free form location string. E.g. `https://news.google.com/news/rss/headlines/section/geo/SanFrancisco` and `https://news.google.com/news/rss/headlines/section/geo/California` both works.

Comment: The project you are linking to is mine. If I remember correctly, I figured out the URL formats by simple guess work. However, Google has dropped the geolocation method in the mean time and it stopped working. I am not sure whether there's a replacement. Also, the "Old link" version for the search query works fine for me.

Comment: For specifying a phrase in a search query, e.g. "global warming", I specify it as global%20warming using %20 as the separator.

Comment: can you pull the image ? I just saw there is no image tag in the rss :(

Comment: Does anyone know how to sort the rss results by date? Is there an attribute that I can add to the url to make this happen? Thanks everyone.

Comment: If the RSS yields no result, try adding `hl={lang}` to the URL parameters.

Answer (score 9):

1. Requests to the Geo endpoint seem to be working again.

   e.g. `https://news.google.com/news/rss/headlines/section/geo/{place_name}`
2. Also, if you use the non-geo search, you can specify a 7-day window by adding `+when:7d` to your search.

   e.g. `https://news.google.com/rss/search?q={key_words}+when:7d`

Answer (score 5):

This options isn't valid anymore:
https://news.google.com/news/rss/headlines/section/topic/{topic}
produces Error 500.

This seems to work:
https://news.google.com/news?cf=all&hl=en&pz=1&ned=us&q=astronomy&output=rss

The Geolocation mentioned above still works too.  You can also specify city and state:
https://news.google.com/news/rss/headlines/section/geo/DenverCo

Comment: I had investigated the URL schemes when writing the [code linked to in the other answer](https://github.com/NichtJens/GoogleNewsRSS2OPML). While some things have changed in the mean time, it seems that currently your answer is wrong: Topics work fine with the given scheme. However, geo location is broken. I also think topics and search queries do not produce the same result, so your equating the both is not correct.

Comment: It is valid if you write the topic in CAPITALS :)

Answer (score 4):

**Updated Google RSS News Feed**

 You can try this as well.

 https://news.google.com/rss?hl=en-NG&gl=NG&ceid=NG:en

Comment: where did you find the documentaton for the options like hl g etc

Comment: I actually did not use any documentation. I just enter this URL into my browser `https://news.google.com/news/rss`. The result is the above URL which I posted. I guess it was just reformated.@PirateApp

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for documentation. This is the best article I found.

https://blog.newscatcherapi.com/google-news-rss/

If using search you can also specify not to include articles with a certain keyword.

e.g. if I wanted to search for pages that contain the word "apple" with out the word "pie" you can specify

`q=apple%20-pie`

or in full

`https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=apple%20-pie&hl=en-GB&gl=UK&ceid=GB:en`

Answer (score -1):

The RSS feed for top stories is the simplest one. Just append RSS to the https://news.google.com and you get the RSS feed of the top stories of your location.

**https://news.google.com/rss**

[Know more](https://www.aakashweb.com/articles/google-news-rss-feed-url/)