# Getting RSS feed in R shiny web app

Tags: r, rss

Is there any way to get RSS feed from various websites (e.g. Google News) in R, and display them in an R shiny interface?

I've tried using the `feedeR` library, but it doesn't work...
Here's my code:

```
library(feedeR)    
feed.extract("news.google.com/search?q=Boston&hl=en&ie=utf-8&num=100&output=rss")
```

I'm getting the following error message:

```
Error: XML content does not seem to be XML: ''
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I removed the shiny tag, as the questions can also be answered without the shiny environment,...

Answer (score 0):

You got the RSS link wrong. The correct format for a search by query is `https://news.google.com/rss/search?q={query}`.

Here's a good answer explaining the format of Google News RSS search queries: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51537262

In your case this will work:

```
library(feedeR)  
myquery <- feed.extract("https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=Boston")
```

The other arguments that you gave in the question are default anyway.

For having a structured dataframe use this:

```
data.frame(myquery$items)
```

Or if you like the `library(tidyverse)`:

```
myquery$items %>% as_tibble()
```