# Google news RSS feed "+when:7d" doesn't work

Tags: rss, google-news

I referred to the other post in stackoverflow in an attempt to set up a RSS feed for Google news for my website. [URL format for Google News RSS feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51537063/url-format-for-google-news-rss-feed)

Here's an example link:
https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=NERU+GmbH+&+Co.+KG+when:7d&hl=de&gl=DE&ceid=DE:de

If you put the link into browser, you will see result with pub date back in 2022, despite the "+when:7d" parameter in the URL

I cannot find any documentation on this as well. Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: Have you consider that maybe the topic you're requiring hasn't any news from that date? - also, Google News RSS "if I recall correctly" is deprecated, so, its URL parameters might not work as expected...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this is because there is no results for the given search terms at the given time range.

If you enter to this link - *which is the non-rss version of your link*:

https://news.google.com/search?q=NERU%20GmbH%20when%3A7d&hl=de&gl=DE&ceid=DE%3Ade

You wont see any results.

Consider also that Google News RSS "*if I recall correctly*" is deprecated, so, its URL parameters might not work as expected.

Comment: thank you! sad to know that it's actually deprecated. the reason I was filtering for 7d is because I'm trying to minimize compute costs when I am using the rss feed at scale with Python transform. Any thoughts on how best to do that?

Comment: @MCHE I have no idea, tbh, but, you can also consider use [Google Custom Search](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/cse/list) - you can search using this tool too and then buil the rss *manually*.  If you can create a [mcve] using Google Colab, I could give it a try.